# Telosys not picking up schema from mySql DB using Xampp

Tags: spring-boot, xampp, eclipse-plugin, telosys

I'm attempting to use Telosys to extract entities, but Telosys is unable to recognize the schema from the locally hosted Mysql database using Xampp.

[Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcrIt.png)

Tried :
Changing URl from jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306 to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
however I still get the error message "no schema"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that "schema" notion doesn't exist in MySQL (because there's also no "schema" with MariaDB, only "catalog").

"No schema" is not an error message (just an information). And it's not a problem as your goal is to retrieve the tables with all the colums ("Get schema" and "Get catalog" are just here to determine what is supported by the database: schema or catalog or both)

With MariaDB I get only the list of "catalogs" and "no schema" (like you)

So, for MySQL I suggest to use only the "catalog" name

Try to configure the "Meta-data" like this :

- **Catalog : your-database-name** ( it seems to be "test" )
- **Schema:  !**  ( "!" means nothing )
- **Table name pattern : %**  (all tables)

And try "Get tables", "Get columns", etc
It should work.
And if you use "!" for both schema and catalog you will get all the tables located in all catalogs

Note: the database name at the end of the JDBC URL has not effect (you can remove it)

Comment: Working fine thanks @Igu 

 Getting tables from metadata
  . catalog = 'test'
  . schema  = ''
  . metadata pattern = '%'
  . metadata types   = [TABLE]
  . include pattern  = ''
  . exclude pattern  = ''
  Processing table #1
  Table #1 : student registered
 Getting columns from metadata for table 'student'
  Column id
  Column studentname
  Column course
  Column fee